How to specify a requestInterceptor with Spring Boot Feign
We need to add a correlation token header (taking value from MDC context) to every outgoing Feign call.
This page describes using interceptors, which sounds like what we need. The problem is that the example uses Feign.builder.requestInterceptor(xxx), but our code does not have this, it's presumably done automatically by Spring.
We have many clients which look like this:
@EnableFeignClients
@FeignClient(value="some-api", url="${client.some-api}")
public interface SomeApi {
    @GetMapping(value = "/someurl", consumes = "application/json")
    public String getSomething(@PathVariable("eventId") String eventId);
    // lots more apis here...
}

Then it's used like this:
@Slf4j
@Component
@Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
public class SomeApiServiceImpl implements SomeApiService {

  private SomeApi someApi;

  @Autowired
  public SomeApiServiceImpl (SomeApi someApi) {     
    this.someApi= someApi;
  }

  public String someMethod() {
    String response = someApi.getSomething(1);
    // ...
  }
}

The APIs are configured like this:
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: ${FEIGN_CONNECT_TIMEOUT:180000}
        readTimeout: ${FEIGN_READ_TIMEOUT:180000}
        loggerLevel: full

Feign is included like this:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

How could we configure the API calls to use an interceptor to inject a header?
The interceptor looks like this:
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;

public  class CorrelationTokenInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        template.header("X-CorrelationToken", "mytest");
    }
}


The answer was quite simple, but is not in the official docs:
@EnableFeignClients
@FeignClient(value="some-api", url="${client.some-api}", **configuration=CorrelationTokenInterceptor.class** )
:

